# WebSphere Application Server/8.0 / Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet

Tags: rest, web-services, websphere, websphere-8

i am just trying to deploy a sample restful web service example on websphere 8.0 but i am getting the following:

**Error**

> [12.02.2013 05:13:07:728 VET] 00000c74  E UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet class=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper method=init org= prod= component= thread=[WebContainer : 370]
>             Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
>   [12.02.2013 05:13:07:728 VET] 00000c74  E UOW= source=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp class=com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp method=logServletError org= prod= component= thread=[WebContainer : 370]
>             SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[jersey-serlvet]: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:262)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
>       at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:852)
>       at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:762)
>       at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:585)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627)
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:85)
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:83)
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:162)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:336)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:629)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1027)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:522)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:311)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:282)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mkyong.rest.JSONService</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 5):

This seem to be a product defect discussed at IBM forums [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=450187), for which a [fix](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM71336) was released consequently. Quoting linked references, problem was;

> The internal ASM libraries used by WebSphere Application Server were
>   accessible by applications. If the application also deploys ASM
>   libraries, it is possible for conflicts to occur.

Some possible workarounds were listed at the [forums](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=450187), which helps to resolve the conflict through classpath modifications. Since you are not 8.5 but 8.0 at the moment, I suggest you raise PMR to  verify yours is the same problem, and receive a fix for your version.